# How can I rerender a Path Shape?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, shapes, draw

I have this code:

```
             <Path                  
                Aspect="Fill"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Stroke="Red"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        
                        <!-- Other Shapes -->                          

                        <EllipseGeometry
                            x:Name="circle"
                            Center="0,0"
                            RadiusX="100"
                            RadiusY="100" />

                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
```

I'm trying to dynamically move the circle. Here is the relevant line of code:
`circle.Center = new Point(var1, var2);`

This has no visible effect.

How can I rerender the shape every time I change its `Center` property in order to present the changes on screen?

Comment: are you updating on the UI thread?

Comment: How can this be done? Can this be done every time `circle.Center = new Point(var1, var2);` gets executed or has to be done on regular intervals?

Comment: use [MainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread).  I'm not positive its the issue, but its the first thing I'd try

Comment: Well, I used `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` for running my code. No luck...

Comment: I have to add this: I noticed that even changing the `Center` attribute's values directly in the XAML code has no effect. All the other changes in the XAML code immediately take effect real-time thanks to XAML Hot Reload, but not this particular change. I have to restart the emulator in order to see the change.

Comment: Might get you going in the right direction: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-add-animation-effects-to-xamarinforms-with-shapes-5b3q354t

Comment: @Andrew I'm currently experimenting with SkiaSharp. Is there a way to rerender the `Path` shape in `Forms`, like the `Canvas` in SkiaSharp?

Comment: You can go through [Path Basics in SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/paths) on how to use `Path`.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I was basic talking about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/path
Anyway, since it didn't worked out I switched to SkiaSharp.