# Is there a way to set the (0,0) point in the center of the Canvas in SkiaSharp?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm using SkiaSharp in Xamarin.Forms (after [an unsuccessful attempt with Path shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75228109/how-can-i-rerender-a-path-shape)) and I have created a Cartesian coordinate system drawn on the Canvas.

Is it possible to move the (0, 0) point in order for it to coincide with the origin point of my Cartesian plain?

In other words, I would like e.g. a circle drawn with `canvas.DrawCircle(0, 0, radius, paint);` to be centered on the Canvas. That would simplify things when giving coordinates in order to draw other stuff.

Comment: Given an `SKCanvas canvas`, use `canvas.Translate(x, y);` You'll have to calculate x and y as half the canvas dimensions.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I thought that I should do that for every object I draw independently, but, no it can be called once before drawing anything on the canvas.